# The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.-in flutter app developing

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error called The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. I'm developing a simple BMI calculator app using flutter, android studio. didn't understand about the error I'm new to flutter. can anyone tell me what to do about this error? followed up this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX9PQI0D-v4) and the code is here [github](https://github.com/Santos-Enoque/flutter_bmi_calculator).

[image]

```
import 'package:bmi_cal/constants/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:bmi_cal/widgets/left_bar.dart';
import 'package:bmi_cal/widgets/right_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController _heightController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _weightController = TextEditingController();
  double _bmiResult = 0;
  String _textResult = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "BMI Calculator",
            style:
            TextStyle(color: accentHexColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: mainHexColor,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 130,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _heightController,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 42,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: accentHexColor),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Height",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 42,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 130,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _weightController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 42,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: accentHexColor),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: "Weight",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 42,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  double _h = double.parse(_heightController.text);
                  double _w = double.parse(_weightController.text);
                  setState(() {
                    _bmiResult = _w / (_h * _h);
                    if(_bmiResult > 25){
                      _textResult = "You\'re over weight";
                    } else if(_bmiResult >= 18.5 && _bmiResult <= 25){
                      _textResult = "You have normal weight";
                    }else{
                      _textResult = "You\'re under weight";
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "Calculate",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: accentHexColor),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  _bmiResult.toStringAsFixed(2),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90, color: accentHexColor),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Visibility(
                  visible: _textResult.isNotEmpty,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      _textResult,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: accentHexColor),
                    ),
                  )),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              LeftBar(barWidth: 40,),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              LeftBar(barWidth: 70),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              LeftBar(barWidth: 40,),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              RightBar(barWidth: 70),
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              RightBar(barWidth: 70),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

> main.dart

```
import 'package:bmi_cal/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BMI calculator',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show the class where the error came from??? LeftBar?

Comment: error is in home.dart

Comment: no! The error clearly is in the LeftBar.dart file, not in home.dart!

Answer (score 0):

This error normally indicates, that the widget you are trying to add to the widget tree does have a constructor similar to the following:

```
const LeftBar({required Key key, @required this.barWidth}) : super(key: key);
```

The error seems to be related to the first required argument with the name key. Just remove the required keyword, since it the key is mostly needed for testing the widget and should be optional.
I checked your source code on github and I dont think it is up to date for this example.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't get the answer

Comment: Is your code in GitHub up to date? I think the error is located in left_bar.dart. The constructor parameter named "key" is probably marked as required which leads to this kind of error. Just remove the required keyword.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg7lD.png)

You have to just try this:
Add "VoidCallback" instead of "Function" onpress.
Remove @ sign
Add required keyword
for detail see the below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IaG9.png)